# How to get List Item from sharepoint list based on ItemID

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem

Dynamically I am adding RadGrid to the page. I need to retrieve list item from the SharePoint list. Say I have 10000 items in the list using `SPQuery`, I will get filtered records as 2000 items. Here is the code for retrieving items from the list

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl.Trim()))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = openWeb(siteUrl.Trim()))
                        {
                            if (!web.Exists)
                                return dt;
                            SPList splist = getList(web, new Guid(listId));
                            if (splist == null)
                                return dt;

                            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scope))
                                query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"" + scope + "\"";
                            query.Query = filterValue;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewFields))
                            {
                                query.ViewFields = viewFields;
                                query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                            }
                            query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Strict;
                            //splist.EnableThrottling = false;
                            query.RowLimit = Convert.ToUInt32(rowLimit);
                            SPListItemCollection myItems = splist.GetItems(query);
                            itemcollection = myItems;
                            if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
                                dt = myItems.GetDataTable();
                            else
                                dt.Merge(myItems.GetDataTable());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return dt;
```

The above code returns the datatable which has 2000 records that will be bound to the RadGrid. I need to get the every 20 records from the table based on the item ID column. I had achieved this using **DataTable.select top 20 rows(based on ItemID column)** for the first page in the RadGrid but how can I retrieve next 20 items(such as 21-40,41-60.....) to show for the second page in the RadGrid. How to retrieve item from the list based on the `itemID` ?

Could anyone provide a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this to see if it helps - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/03/23/adding-paging-to-spgridview-when-using-custom-data-sources.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1) This is ok but uou should use LINQ Query

2) There are things like SKIP and TAKE in LINQ

3) If I have loaded 20 records in first time and in the second time I can skip the first 20 and I can take the second 20 records or items.